# Modify the value in text field before showing in Ext.grid.Panel Column

Tags: javascript, extjs

I need to modify a value in text field when I click a column in Ext.grid.Panel, so I used beforeshow listener like

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data:{'items':[
        {"name":"Lisa", "email":"lisa@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-111-1224"},
        {"name":"Bart", "email":"bart@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1234"},
        {"name":"Homer", "email":"homer@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1244"},
        {"name":"Marge", "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"}
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items'
        }
    }
});


Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', editor: 'textfield'},
        {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false,
                listeners : {
                    beforeshow : function(obj, event, eOpts) {
                        alert();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone'}
    ],
    selModel: 'cellmodel',
    plugins: {
        ptype: 'cellediting',
        clicksToEdit: 1
    },
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/qiv

But the listener is not firing when I click on the column, can you please let me know how can I modify the value before showing in the text field when I click on the column.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a response from Sencha Forum,

If any one is interested please follow the following code and links

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data:{'items':[
        {"name":"Lisa", "email":"lisa@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-111-1224"},
        {"name":"Bart", "email":"bart@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1234"},
        {"name":"Homer", "email":"homer@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1244"},
        {"name":"Marge", "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"}
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items'
        }
    }
});

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', editor: 'textfield'},
        {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false
            }
        },
        {header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone'}
    ],
    selModel: 'cellmodel',
    plugins: {
        ptype: 'cellediting',
        clicksToEdit: 1,
        listeners : {
            beforeedit: function(ed, context){
                var field,
                    column = grid.headerCt.getHeaderAtIndex(context.colIdx);

                if (context.column.dataIndex === 'email') {
                    console.log('ashok');
                }    
            }
        }

    },
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Fiddle:- https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/qiv

Forum Post:- [Forum Post Link](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?303288-Need-to-modify-value-in-text-field-before-showing-it-in-Ext.grid.Panel)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a value different from the one stored, I think a better way is to use a [Renderer](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) in your column.

Answer (score 0):

Simply move your listener code from plugin to grid.
That is instead of ...

```
plugins: {
        ptype: 'cellediting',
        clicksToEdit: 1,
        listeners : {
            beforeedit: function(ed, context){
                var field,
                    column = grid.headerCt.getHeaderAtIndex(context.colIdx);

                if (context.column.dataIndex === 'email') {
                    context.column.field.setValue('ashok');
                    console.log(context.column);
                }    
            }
        }

    },
```

Move the listener to grid. :)

```
plugins: {
    ptype: 'cellediting',
    clicksToEdit: 1,

},
listeners : {
        beforeedit: function(ed, context){
            var field,
                column = grid.headerCt.getHeaderAtIndex(context.colIdx);

            if (context.column.dataIndex === 'email') {
                context.column.field.setValue('ashok');
                console.log(context.column);
            }    
        }
 },
```

Comment: Thanks Vick that is the modified code by me from Sencha Forum :)